# How I can generate the pdf using AddImageUrl from ABCpdf after the page is loaded complete

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, abcpdf

I want to add the thumbnail of a web page to pdf document,

I added like this:

```
    Doc generatedoc = new Doc();
    generatedoc.HtmlOptions.UseScript = true;

    string urlToHtmlPage = "http://example.com?param1=30&param2=true";
    int generatedId = generatedoc.AddImageUrl(urlToHtmlPage);

    generatedoc.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("htmlimport.pdf"));
    generatedoc.Clear();
```

In url I send two parameters, depending on a parameter in page is added a class for various html tags, for example:

```
<div class="cssClass <%=param2==true?"secondCssClass":""%>">some html tags</div>
```

or

```
<span class="<%= param2==true?"secondCssClass":"" %>"> some text </span>
```

Inside the style

```
<style type="text/css">
    .secondCssClass
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

pdf is generated ok but secondCssClass is not added to my tags and css is not applying
I try to set big time out but also css is not applying

I set time out like this:

```
generatedoc.HtmlOptions.Timeout = 1000000;
```

or

```
generatedoc.HtmlOptions.OnLoadScript = "(function(){ window.ABCpdf_go = false;
            setTimeout(function(){ window.ABCpdf_go = true; }, 1000000); })();";
```

or RenderWait() and RenderComplete()

```
   generatedoc.HtmlOptions.OnLoadScript = @"
    window.external.ABCpdf_RenderWait(); 
    window.external.ABCpdf_RenderComplete(true);";
```

but anyway CSS did not apply
when I load url in browser css is applying
some proposals?

Comment: If you try to hit http://example.com?param1=30&param2=true from the browser, does it return the correct result?

Comment: @malkassem css class is not added to html tags and my style is not applying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your response to the comment that you see the issue even in the browser tells that this is not an ABCPDF issue.

I think the problem lies in the following:

```
<div class="cssClass <%=param2==true?"secondCssClass":""%>">some html tags</div>
```

AND

```
<span class="<%= param2==true?"secondCssClass":"" %>"> some text </span>
```

If that code is exactly what you have in your running code, then you will need to make an adjustment those lines:

1. Accessing URL parameters, you need to use the Request object
2. URL parameters are text, and your comparison has them as boolean

Code should be as follows:

```
<div class="cssClass <%= Request.QueryString("param2")=="true"?"secondCssClass":"" %>">some html tags</div>
```

AND

```
<span class="<%= Request.QueryString("param2")=="true"?"secondCssClass":"" %>"> some text </span>
```

I recommend that you test this in the browser prior to testing it via ABCPDF.